# Invariant Violation: View config getter callback for component `a` using React-Router Links

Tags: reactjs, react-native

```
<Link to="/signup"><Text>sign up</Text></Link>
<Link to="/login"><Text>login</Text></Link>
<Link to="/"><Text>Home</Text></Link>
```

If I include this above in my code in react-native it will give me the error

```
Invariant Violation: View config getter callback for component `a` must be a function (received `undefined`). Make sure to start component names with a capital letter.
```

Anyone know why this is happening?

Comment: You are not showing the code where is the problem

Comment: Where does <Link> get imported from? If it is as I suspect `react-router-web` or similar, that'll be why. `react-native` doesn't know about "<a>" as a DOM element so it tries to use it as a React element. You'll need to use a React Native specific routing lib

Comment: Oh okay, that was my issue. I just used react-router-native and now I don't have any errors.

Answer (score 0):

this messsage says that your React Classs Component name should start with capital letter
..like this 'MyComponent'

Answer (score 0):

All React component names must start with a capital letter. If you start a component name with a lowercase letter, it will be treated like a built-in element like a `<div>` or a `<span>`. This is because of the way JSX works.

https://reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#user-defined-components-must-be-capitalized

Comment: I only showed the `<Link>` components because it was the section of my code showing the errors. I guess what was happening was the <Link> components were turning into a `<a>` component.